# Write/Read a stream of data (double) using named pipes in C++

Tags: c++, linux, pipe

I am trying to develop a little application in C++, within a Linux environment, which does the following:

1) gets a data stream (a series of arrays of doubles) from the output of a 'black-box' and writes it to a pipe. The black-box can be thought as an ADC;

2) reads the data stream from the pipe and feeds it to another application which requires these data as stdin;

Unfortunately, I was not able to find tutorials or examples. The best way I found to realize this is summarized in the following test-bench example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define FIFO "/tmp/data"

using namespace std;

int main() {

   int fd;
   int res = mkfifo(FIFO,0777);
   float *writer = new float[10];
   float *buffer = new float[10];

   if( res == 0 ) {
      cout<<"FIFO created"<<endl;

      int fres = fork();

      if( fres == -1 ) {
         // throw an error
      }
      if( fres == 0 )
      {
         fd = open(FIFO, O_WRONLY);

         int idx = 1;
         while( idx <= 10) {
            for(int i=0; i<10; i++) writer[i]=1*idx;

            write(fd, writer, sizeof(writer)*10);
         }
         close(fd);
      }
      else
      {
         fd = open(FIFO, O_RDONLY);
         while(1) {
            read(fd, buffer, sizeof(buffer)*10);

            for(int i=0; i<10; i++) printf("buf: %f",buffer[i]);
            cout<<"\n"<<endl;
         }
         close(fd);
      }

   }

   delete[] writer;
   delete[] buffer;

}
```

The problem is that, by running this example, I do not get a printout of all the 10 arrays I am feeding to the pipe, whereas I keep getting always the first array (filled by 1).

Any suggestion/correction/reference is very welcome to make it work and learn more about the behavior of pipes.

EDIT:

Sorry guys! I found a very trivial error in my code: in the while loop within the writer part, I am not incrementing the index idx......once I correct it, I get the printout of all the arrays. 
But now I am facing another problem: when using a lot of large arrays, these are randomly printed out (the whole sequence is not printed); as if the reader part is not able to cope with the speed of the writer. Here is the new sample code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define FIFO "/tmp/data"

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char** argv) {

   int fd;
   int res = mkfifo(FIFO,0777);
   int N(1000);
   float writer[N];
   float buffer[N];

   if( res == 0 ) {
      cout<<"FIFO created"<<endl;

      int fres = fork();

      if( fres == -1 ) {
         // throw an error
      }
      if( fres == 0 )
      {
         fd = open(FIFO, O_WRONLY | O_NONBLOCK);

         int idx = 1;
         while( idx <= 1000 ) {
            for(int i=0; i<N; i++) writer[i]=1*idx;

            write(fd, &writer, sizeof(float)*N);
            idx++;
         }
         close(fd);
         unlink(FIFO);
      }
      else
      {
         fd = open(FIFO, O_RDONLY);
         while(1) {
            int res = read(fd, &buffer, sizeof(float)*N);

            if( res == 0 ) break;
            for(int i=0; i<N; i++) printf(" buf: %f",buffer[i]);
            cout<<"\n"<<endl;

         }
         close(fd);
      }

   }

}
```

Is there some mechanism to implement in order to make the write() wait until read() is still reading data from the fifo, or am I missing something trivial also in this case?

Thank you for those who have already given answers to the previous version of my question, I have implemented the suggestions.

Comment: Why do you allocate those arrays dynamically? Also, the sizeof()  in your call to write is wrong, it should be sizeof(float), though it may work by accident.

Answer (score 0):

The arguments to `read` and `write` are incorrect. Correct ones:

```
write(fd, writer, 10 * sizeof *writer);

read(fd, buffer, 10 * sizeof *buffer);
```

Also, these functions may do partial reads/writes, so that the code needs to check the return values to determine whether the operation must be continued.

---

Not sure why `while( idx <= 10)` loop in the writer, this loop never ends. Even on a 5GHz CPU. Same comment for the reader.